# Google BigQuery: Error 413 Response is too large

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

This is an issue that seems difficult to reproduce at times but then crops up over and over again leading me to think it might be to do with quotas but I can't see any of them set on our account.

```
var myQuery = 'SELECT * FROM [' + myProjectId + ':' + myDatasetId + '.' + historyTable + '] WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM [' + myProjectId + ':'  + myDatasetId + '.' + federatedTable + '])'

  // Overwrite the history table with a version with only the records that are NOT in federated
   var job = {
    configuration: {
      query: {
        query: myQuery,
        maximumBillingTier: "2",
        writeDisposition:'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        useQueryCache: true,
        allowLargeResults: true,
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: myProjectId,
          datasetId: myDatasetId,
          tableId: historyTable
        }}
    }};

  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, myProjectId);



var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;



// Wait until that job completes


// Check on status of the Query Job.
  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(myProjectId, jobId);
    Logger.log("Not Done");
  }
```

The error occurs on the line

```
queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(myProjectId, jobId);
```

The table has 91 columns and about 25,000 rows so should be nowhere near the 128mb limit for responses.

Have read through every Stackoverflow question that is similar and tried everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to run a query job which writes the results to the destination table specified. However, in your loop you are calling `getQueryResults` which [will request all the results](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults) of the query itself each time it's called. This is what is causing the 413.

I don't think this is what you are really trying to do.

Instead, simply poll the `job.status.state` to get the [job resource](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#resource) to determine when it's finished. That won't pull all the results over-the-wire. For example:

```
function runQuery() {
  var projectId = 'XXXXXX';
  var myQuery = 'SELECT TOP(word, 300) AS word, COUNT(*) AS word_count ' +
      'FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare WHERE LENGTH(word) > 10;'

  var job = {
    configuration: {
      query: {
        query: myQuery,
        writeDisposition:'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        useQueryCache: true,
        allowLargeResults: true,
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: 'XXXXXX',
          datasetId: 'test',
          tableId: 'test_table'
        }}
  }};

  var job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId);
  Logger.log(job.status.state);
  var jobId = job.jobReference.jobId;

  // Check on status of the Query Job.
  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (job.status.state !== 'DONE') {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    job = BigQuery.Jobs.get(projectId, jobId);
    Logger.log(job.status.state);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Graham but I have tried that already and makes no difference, I'll update the code above to show it's included, or is that bad form? If so let me know and I'll undo.

Also, that config change should only matter if the return is > 128mb compressed. Which is this nowhere near.

Comment: Wait a second. Does `BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(myProjectId, jobId);` try and pull the actual results of the query over-the-wire? Is this really what you want to do?

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!